# nextflow: declares 1 input channel but 0 were specified

Tags: nextflow

Please see below code:

```
params.outdir = './results'
params.reads = "/Users/user/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_{R1,R2}_xxx.fastq.gz"


println "reads ${params.reads}"


process check {
    tag {sample_id}

input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

output:stdout

    script:

    """ 
    echo "hello  ${sample_id} \n"

    """

}

workflow {
    check().view()

}
```

It gives following error:

> reads /Users/user/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_{R1,R2}_xxx.fastq.gz Process
> `check` declares 1 input channel but 0 were specified

How do I two channel or one channel? Sorry new to nextflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because you did not call `check` with any input channels. It was expecting a single input channel but none were specified. If you require [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels), most of the time what you'll want is one [queue channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) and one or more [value channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel). Note that a value channel is implicitly created by a process when it is invoked with a simple value, like a `file` object. For example:

```
params.reads = "/Users/name/Downloads/tiny/normal/*_R{1,2}_xxx.fastq.gz"
params.ref_fasta = "/path/to/GRCh38.fa"

params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process check {

    tag { sample_id }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/check", mode: 'copy'
    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)
    path fasta

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("out.txt")

    script:

    """
    echo "My sample: ${sample_id}:"
    ls -1 ${reads}
    ls -1 ${fasta}

    touch out.txt
    """

}
```

```
workflow {

    reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )

    ref_fasta = file( params.ref_fasta )

    check(reads, ref_fasta).view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [small_feynman] DSL2 - revision: 90fca4d9fd
executor >  local (3)
[a1/eab4e5] process > check (foo) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
[baz, /path/to/work/52/a93d1281daab5db136ffe96c34da2e/out.txt]
My sample: baz:
baz_R1_xxx.fastq.gz
baz_R2_xxx.fastq.gz
GRCh38.fa

[bar, /path/to/work/80/7b6dc52b6c620038368898a4660598/out.txt]
My sample: bar:
bar_R1_xxx.fastq.gz
bar_R2_xxx.fastq.gz
GRCh38.fa

[foo, /path/to/work/a1/eab4e5c20977b36ee71453430c3f0b/out.txt]
My sample: foo:
foo_R1_xxx.fastq.gz
foo_R2_xxx.fastq.gz
GRCh38.fa
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborative answer. I have questions: 1) what does `output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("out.txt")` do? Can I not use `output: stdout` to print/see? I believe debug true is used in place of echo true.

Comment: @DeathMetal The [outputs](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#outputs) block lets you declare the outputs of your process script using one or more channels. In this case, it is a channel of tuples, where each tuple contains a file called `out.txt` as the second element. If one or more commands in your process script _had_ written to _stdout_, then you _could_ use the [`stdout`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#output-type-stdout) qualifier to declare those. However, you are usually better of redirecting stdout to a file and then declaring the file in the usual way.

Comment: @DeathMetal Yes the [debug](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#debug) directive indeed replaces the older `echo` directive.

Comment: thank you. Can you please help with post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76477346/nextflow-create-index-get-path